# Clojure throws ClassCastException on java.util.Collection

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to use an [MPD library](http://www.thejavashop.net/javampd/javadoc/index.html) in Java in Clojure. Everything has gone well, but these methods that return a `java.util.Collection` get bad reception in REPL. Let's define

```
(def mpd (org.bff.javampd.MPD. "localhost" ))
(def pl (.getMPDPlaylist mpd))
(def db (.getMPDDatabase mpd))
```

And now some methods play ok:

```
(.getSongList pl) ; returns List<MPDSong>
```

works well. But for instance every `db` (MPDDatabase) method return `Collection<MPDSong>` (according to their API):

```
(.findAlbum db "Crises") ; returns Collection<MPDSong>
java.lang.ClassCastException (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
```

Doesn't work  that well. Why is that, how to fix it?

Stack trace follows:

```
hello.hello=> (.findAlbum db "Crises")
java.lang.ClassCastException (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
hello.hello=> (.printStackTrace *e)
java.lang.ClassCastException (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5440)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5391)
    at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2382)
    at clojure.main$repl$read_eval_print__5624.invoke(main.clj:183)
    at clojure.main$repl$fn__5629.invoke(main.clj:204)
    at clojure.main$repl.doInvoke(main.clj:204)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:422)
    at user$eval13$acc__808__auto____14$fn__16.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
    at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:2990)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.boxArg(Reflector.java:364)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.boxArgs(Reflector.java:397)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:55)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28)
    at hello.hello$eval44.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:8)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5424)
    ... 9 more
nil
```

Comment: The actual source of the exception isn't clear from what you've posted.  Try calling (.printStackTrace *e).

Comment: @Alex, oh thanks for that. I tried to find the way to print the trace to no avail. Iincluded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the API Documentation is invalid (checking using clojure.contrib.repl-utils):

```
user> (show MPDDatabase "findAlbum$")
===  public org.bff.javampd.MPDDatabase  ===
[ 1] findAlbum : Collection (MPDAlbum)
```

and you need to a intermediate MPDAlbum object:

```
user> (.findAlbum db (MPDAlbum. "Crisis"))
#<ArrayList []>
```

Comment: Wow, never'd have guessed. I'm gonna write that guy an angry email about that. :) For you, double thanks for hinting at `repl-utils` and the answer.